# URL Shortener is not previewing the target page

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I'm creating an internal (links only from our site) URL shortening service. When I use a service like bit .ly or tinyurl and then post the shortened link to facebook, the preview of the target (full link) is displayed. When I try to do this with my own page, it displays the redirection page.

For example http://youtu.be/2323 would map to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123456, but my link

http://exam.pl/2323 will show http://exam.pl/Redirect.aspx instead of the actual page in the database. Do I need to the redirection on the server itself or something?

Thanks

UPDATE: Solved with an HttpHandler like in the answer below. I changed the response because apparently Response.Redirect automatically sends a 302 status whereas 301 is more correct.

```
context.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
context.Response.AddHeader("Location", httplocation);
context.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using an http handler instead of an actual page to do the redirect http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001

I also recommend you provide a proper 301 http status http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Update: (This is purley from memory and may not compile as is)

```
public class IISHandler1 : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string url = content.Request.Url.ToString();
            string newUrl = Translate(url);
            context.Response.ResponseCode = 301;
            context.Response.Redirect(newUrl);
        }

    }
```

You modules get processed AFTER handlers so you should handle the request in a handler. If not possibly to handle then just ignore it and let it pass through

Comment: Ok that sounds like a good idea but I'm having trouble getting the request from my module to my handler. My module currently does a server.transfer to my aspx page if the URL format matches. How can I transfer that to an HttpHandler?

Comment: Update my answer. Your modules only get processed after the handlers. Move whatever code you're using into the ProcessRequest method in the handler.

Comment: Thank's I was making it way hard than it needed to be. The handler works well. I changed the Response part a bit and updated in my post.